# Android - Image Loading from WebPage in WebView

Tags: android, image, android-webview

I am trying to load a wiki web page into a native Android WebView with WebView.loadUrl(String url). It works and displays all of the web content, except for the images. However, I have not found a reason for this. Does anyone know why image resources would not load automatically? Is there a method I need to overwrite or a parameter that needs to be set? I can't find anything in the documentation - it looks like the default settings should allow for automatic image loading. Any information would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
setWebViewClient(mWebView);
setWebSettings(mWebView);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://my_wiki_url_goes_here/");

private void setWebViewClient(WebView mWebView) {
    WebViewClient client = new WikiWebViewClient();
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(client);
}

private void setWebSettings(WebView mWebView) {
    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

public class WikiWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;   
    }

}
```

Printing the url onLoadResource(), I see that the image urls generally start with "data:image/png;base64,". I don't think that should makes a difference or not - it works in the web browser.

Comment: Are all images not loaded ? Maybe this link could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487734/image-not-loading-through-android-webview

Comment: Thanks, I did see this link, but I don't have access to the images to resize (I am strictly working on front-end). Is there any other possibility besides image size? Thanks!

Comment: Which android version do you use ? Maybe cached images are not loaded ? Hows the url, if its not confidential :)

Comment: 4.1.2 - and looks like enabling DOM Storage was all I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, looks like simply enabling DOM storage did the trick.

```
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

If I don't receive a better explanation or solution, I will accept this answer once I am able to

Comment: Jo, looks like it is disabled as default, maybe for security reasons. This settings allows you to store data and reuse it. So the images are not loaded, because it wasnt allowed to store them on your device. Very interesting :).

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage